# Null Pointer in catch block

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, try-catch, throws

I am using a try catch block to catch an exception. The console shows that it is throwing a null value. But it is not going to the catch block.

```
try {
        System.out.println("Exception here "+SomeObject.getValue());
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        SomeObject so = new SomeObject();
    }
    SomeObject.setValue(); 
}
```

How could this be handled. Can I also use method level `throws NullPointerException` ?

Comment: Please post the stack trace and identify the line from which the exception is thrown.

Comment: strange!! why to handle null pointer exception while null values should be handled by cheeking values for any null values

Comment: What do you mean that the console shows it is throwing a null value?  Your println is not in the catch block.

Comment: Use exceptions in really exception cases. Provided code shows incorrect exception usage. Why not just check that `SomeObject` is null?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It indeed would have went inside the catch block. There is another potential NullPointerException at the line (assuming you are trying to say)

```
so.setValue();
```

Having said that it is not advised to throw RuntimeException. It is better you handle NullPointerException in your code not through try/catch but through simple condition checks

Comment: From the statement `SomeObject so = new SomeObject()`, it appears that `SomeObject` is a class name. This would suggest that `setValue()` is a static (class) function. If there was a NPE thrown, it would be from inside that function, not from this statement.

Comment: @TedHopp : Agreed. Corrected answer

Answer (score 0):

it is a bad idea to catch UnChecked Exceptions, rather than catching NullPointerExcetpion, you can simple check for null values in an If condition.

```
if(SomeObject.getValue()!=null)
System.out.println(SomeObject.getValue());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put another try block inside catch

```
try {
    doSomething();
} catch (IOException) {
         try {
                  doSomething();
         } catch (IOException e) {
                 throw new ApplicationException("Failed twice at doSomething" +
                 e.toString());
         }          
} catch (Exception e) {
}
```